# Using a list made in a function outside of that function, python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am having a problem using a list that is made in a function that I am iterating. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
def get_things(i):
    html=str(site[i])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    browser.get(html);
    playerlist=[]
    teamlist=[]
    all_players = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='name']")
    all_teams = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='last']")
    for a in all_players:
        playerlist.append(str(a.text))
    print playerlist
    for td in all_teams:
        teamlist.append(str(td.text))
    print teamlist
    browser.quit()
    return playerlist, teamlist
```

I then want to use teamlist and playerlist in another function later in my program.

```
for i in xrange(0,2):
    get_things(i)
    print teamlist    #This is where Im told teamlist doesn't exist
    print playerlist   #This is where I'm told playerlist doesn't exist
    print_sheet(teamlist, playerlist)
```

Where the two print statements are for me to make sure that the program is picking up items as it should. My problem, though, is that I am told that teamlist and playerlist do not exist.

```
NameError: name 'teamlist' is not defined
```

I believe that the return statement should make these available to the rest of the program, but it is not.

How can I make these lists available to the rest of the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are need to assign the return to values from `get_things` to some variables

```
for i in xrange(0,2):
    playerlist , teamlist = get_things(i) # missing this
    print teamlist    #This is where Im told teamlist doesn't exist
    print playerlist   #This is where I'm told playerlist doesn't exist
    print_sheet(teamlist, playerlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
(teamlist, playerlist)=get_things(I)
```

As your function's returning something, you need to handle it.

Example

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
n=add(6,8)
print n #n is 14
```